# Nothing persisted to database despite successfully start and terminate solving

Tags: optaplanner, kie-workbench

Tables for all entities were created automatically upon deployment. However, when making REST API to create, start and terminate solver nothing was persisted to database despite successfully start and terminate solving. See below for the log. I am using kie-wb and execution server installed from jbpm installer 7.0.0.Beta6.

Am I missing anything?

`2017-03-14 23:30:06,971 INFO  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl] (EJB default - 4) KieModule was added: ZipKieModule[releaseId=org.optaplanner.examples:cloud-balancing:1.0,file=C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\optaplanner\examples\cloud-balancing\1.0\cloud-balancing-1.0.jar]
2017-03-14 23:30:07,584 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (EJB default - 4) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: org.optaplanner.examples:cloud-balancing:1.0
        ...]
2017-03-14 23:30:07,601 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (EJB default - 4) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2017-03-14 23:30:07,687 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (EJB default - 4) HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2017-03-14 23:30:08,114 INFO  [org.kie.server.services.impl.KieServerImpl] (EJB default - 4) Container cloud-balancing_1.0 (for release id org.optaplanner.examples:cloud-balancing:1.0) successfully started
2017-03-14 23:30:23,379 INFO  [org.kie.workbench.common.screens.datasource.management.util.ServiceUtil] (DataSourceManagementBootstrapTimer) Getting reference to managed bean: WildflyDataSourceProvider
2017-03-14 23:30:23,433 INFO  [org.kie.workbench.common.screens.datasource.management.util.ServiceUtil] (DataSourceManagementBootstrapTimer) Getting reference to managed bean: WildflyDriverProvider
2017-03-14 23:31:26,260 INFO  [org.kie.server.services.optaplanner.SolverServiceBase] (default task-55) Solver 'solver1' successfully created in container 'cloud-balancing_1.0'
2017-03-14 23:31:37,659 INFO  [org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver] (pool-11-thread-1) Solving started: time spent (62), best score (-1init/0hard/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), random (JDK with seed 0).
2017-03-14 23:31:37,699 INFO  [org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase] (pool-11-thread-1) Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (103), best score (0hard/-1000soft), score calculation speed (76/sec), step total (1).
2017-03-14 23:31:48,198 INFO  [org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.termination.BasicPlumbingTermination] (default task-57) Terminating solver early.
2017-03-14 23:31:48,199 INFO  [org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase] (pool-11-thread-1) Local Search phase (1) ended: time spent (10603), best score (0hard/-1000soft), score calculation speed (66839/sec), step total (1).
2017-03-14 23:31:48,201 INFO  [org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver] (pool-11-thread-1) Solving ended: time spent (10604), best score (0hard/-1000soft), score calculation speed (66146/sec), phase total (2), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE).`

Comment: I added JPA annotation to all classes as per Persistent Storage section of the documentation (http://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#integrationWithJpaAndHibernate) , deployed the project to Kie Server and made call using  Optaplanner REST API (https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e25373)

Answer (score 0):

Optaplanner execution Server keeps the best solution in memory while solving and after solving. Do a REST call to collect it. It doesn't automatically store it on some database, although you can create a jira for that feature request.

Comment: As described in http://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#integrationWithJpaAndHibernate "Enrich the domain POJO’s (solution, entities and problem facts) with JPA annotations to store them in a database." Are you saying we have to write Java application/web application to explicitly call save on entity manager (or alike) to store them in database? And, when running in kie execution server container no such calls are made to save objects.

Comment: That section isn't about Execution Server, but I 've added "and call EntityManager.persist()" in the next release to remove all doubt.